# Probability - Messaging problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

> We're given a sender and a receiver. The sender sends "words" from the set $ W = \{00, 01, 10, 11\}$. For a word $v \in W$, the event $S_v$ describes the word $v$ being sent and the event $R_v$ is the event that $v$ is received. It is given that $P(S_{00}) = 0.9, P(S_{01}) = 0.06, $ $ P(S_{10}) = 0.03,$ $ P(S_{11}) = 0.01$. Transmission errors can also occur, these are given by:
>
> $$P(R_w \mid S_v)=\begin{cases}0.81&\text{if }w=v,\\
> 0.09&\text{if }d(v, w) = 1,\\
> 0.01&\text{if }d(v, w) = 2.\\
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Here, $d(v, w)$ is the number of places where the words $v$ and $w$ differ. For example: $d(00, 01) = 1, d(00, 11) = 2.$
>
> Calculate the probabilities $P (S_v \mid R_w)$ for all $v, w \in W.$

I tried using Bayes' rule: $P(S_v \ R_w) = \dfrac{P(R_w \mid S_v) * P(S_v)}{P(R_w)}$ but how do I get $P(R_w)?$ I don't think I'm supposed to use this $|W|^2 = 16$ times.

There must be a way to calculate a formula for all $v, w \in W$, but I'm not sure how to do so. Can anyone give me a hint? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P(S_v | R_w) = \frac{P(R_w \cap S_v)}{P(R_w)} = \frac{P(R_w \cap S_v)}{\sum_{u \in W}P(R_w \cap S_u)} = \frac{P(R_w | S_v)P(S_v)}{\sum_{u \in W} P(R_w | S_u)P(S_u)}
$$

Each of the quantities in the summation above can be calculated because they are all functions of the $16$ quantities $P(R_w | S_v)P(S_v)$ for $v,w \in W$. These quantities are known to us.

(You will need to calculate them, there is no shortcut for that. It helps to make a table of $P(R_w | S_v)P(S_v)$ for $v , w \in W$. From the table you can easily see how to get the Bayes' ratios.)

Comment: Why is $P(R_w) = \sum_{u \in W}P(R_w \cap S_u)?$ Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Because the event $R_w$ is equal to the event $(R_w \cap S_{11}) \cup (R_w \cap S_{10} )\cup (R_{w} \cap S_{01}) \cup (R_w \cap S_{00})$ , where the union is disjoint. In words : the event "I received $w$" breaks into four disjoint events : "I received $w$ when $u$ was sent" for each $u \in W$. By the laws of probability, the probability of the union of disjoint events is the sum, so that is why the sum comes.

Answer (score 0):

$P(R_w)=0.81P(S_w)+0.01P(S_{\bar{w}})+0.09(1-P(S_w)-P(S_{\bar{w}}))$, where $\bar{w}$ is the complement of $w$.